# How to mount a host drive as a hard drive in Windows 8 when running inside VMware

Tags: hard-drive, hardware, vmware-player

I am using VMWare 6.2 (Non-commercial version ) to use win 8 on ubuntu 14.04.

I want to add my drive (/dev/sda4) as a drive in Win 8 which is running on VMware.

So when I add a hardware on the VMware ... it asks to run vm ware on root privilege.

[image: screen shot]

Comment: run vmware with superuser do privilege.

Answer (score 0):

Once you’ve installed the guest additions, enable shared folders by adding a folder from your host machine in the settings for the guest machine. To do this, first make sure the guest machine is powered off. Then, select the guest machine in the list on the left of the VirtualBox Manager and click Settings on the toolbar.

check link below

http://www.howtogeek.com/187703/how-to-access-folders-on-your-host-machine-from-an-ubuntu-virtual-machine-in-virtualbox/

Comment: i am using vmware ...